# View takes more time comparing to a query

Tags: mysql, view, union

I have created this view using `union`

```
create view sdc_emp_leaves2 as
select * from sdc_leave1 union
select * from sdc_leave2015
```

When i querying data from the below query takes `(1035 total, Query took 0.0010 seconds.)`

```
select * from sdc_leave1 union select * from sdc_leave2015
```

Whereas querying data from the view takes `(Query took 0.0240 seconds.)`

Why this much of difference in the query. Is there any way to reduce the time difference.

Comment: How many times have you repeated the selects? If you had the slower first mabye something was cached in mysql

Comment: I used union in this 2 select query

Comment: Were still talking milliseconds here - you should run each select 10 times at least and check execution times